# Prestashop Upgrade Issue - Products Page not showing anything

Tags: upgrade, updates, prestashop

I just upgraded a prestashop from 1.2.x to 1.5.4.1
everything seems to work but products page is not showing anything at all
every other page under catalog and the rest of the back office work fine
I just cant seem to figure it out
BTW I am new to prestashop, so it may be a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting errors on product page but the `display_errors` are disabled go to `/config/defines.inc.php` and replace off with on for `else`

```
 else
{
@ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```

it will display all errors

Comment: i've found the issue...
it was something that wasn't configurated correctly with my webhost
but thanks anyways.. this was useful for my current problem :P

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after moving to the new Server. I couldn't open any Product page in my Prestashop. Regenerating the .htaccess and many other tricks didn't help me. To my surprise the final solution was so simple... Changed Preferences->SEO&URLs->Shop domain from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com.